# How do I figure out which react-select style keys map to which components

Tags: react-select

In the documentation for react-select, there is a list of keys, but it's hard to know just from the titles which keys map to which elements in the select component.  Is there a guide somewhere that makes this more clear?

https://react-select.com/styles#style-object

Answer (score 6):

Here are the keys with the corresponding elements outlined in red:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This actually already is in the docs.  It's just not easy to find if you start from the styling section.

https://react-select.com/components#replaceable-components